# Angular time validation

Tags: angularjs, validation

In the following sample of code I am creating an input to take the time that for ex. a meeting is over.

```
           <input ui-timepicker
                                   name="EventTimePickerTo"
                                   id="EventTimePickerTo"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   autocomplete="off"
                                   attachlevel="-1"
                                   placeholder="@WebResources.PlaceholderEndTime"
                                   ng-model="EventDetails.DateTimeTo"
                                   time-pattern="@ValidatorRegex.ValidTimeOrEmpty"
                                   ng-disabled="EventDetails.Permissions.TimePickerDisabled"
                                   ng-change="SaveEventDetails()"
                                   ng-blur="SaveEventDetails()" />
```

What I want is to validate that the input should have a max time to 14:00 and print an error message in case of time>14:00.
Unfortunatelly ng-max doesn't work..
Any help is welcome!

Comment: You can make this validation in your ng-change function, check the time in there

Comment: create your own validator : http://angularjs.io/how-to-create-a-custom-input-validator-with-angularjs/.

Answer (score 0):

try using the `min` and `max` attributes, but set date as a string.
for example

```
<input class="col-xs-12 -th-txt" type="date" name="date_field_{{field.Id}}"
                       ng-if="field.ValidationMinValue && field.ValidationMaxValue"
                       ng-required="field.Required"
                       min="{{field.ValidationMinValue}}"
                       max="{{field.ValidationMaxValue}}"
                       ng-model="field.model" />
```

Comment: Tried to pass the max value as:`max="'14:00:00'" ` or even `max="14:00:00" ` and handle like: `<li ng-show="forms.EventDetailsForm.EventTimePickerTo.$error.time"><b>Not Valid!</b></li>` but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

For some reason ng-max (or max) is not collaborating with ui-timepicker. So, I placed the checking in the allready existing function:

```
   var hoursfromdate = ed.DateTimeTo.getHours();
                        if (hoursfromdate > "14") {
                            console.log("not a valid time!");
                        } else
                            console.log("valid time!");
```

A problem that I faced is that it is not possible to compare a datetime variable with a time! So I had to extract the hours information..